# EF - I can not assign values to foreign keys via Create

Tags: entity-framework

I'm a fairly green beginner (1 year training altogether) in C#. 
My assignment was to create tables in a DB through Visual Studio 2010 - I did via EF. Now I want to write a simple Console program to fill those tables with values. In SQL MS they look right. In the last few lines of my code, I get the error msg that the CreateBestellung()-method only takes two arguments though. That'll be the two columns I created in this table. But how do I assign values to the foreign key fields? Couldn't find anything about this so far.

```
private static void bestellungAnlegen(playgroundEntities context)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Neue Bestellung anlegen");

        int kdId = -1;
        int wrId = -1;
        int anzahl = 0;
        int id = -1;

        // Validierung der Werte
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Kunden ID: ");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out kdId))
            {
                kdId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

        } while (kdId == -1);

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Waren ID: ");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out kdId))
            {
                kdId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

        } while (wrId == -1);

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Anzahl: ");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out anzahl))
            {
                if (anzahl >= 0)
                {
                    anzahl = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                }
                else anzahl = 0;

            }

        } while (anzahl == 0);

        Bestellung neueBestellung =
            Bestellung.CreateBestellung(id, anzahl, kdId, wrId);
        context.Bestellungen.AddObject(neueBestellung);
    }
```

Comment: Did you declare the foreign fields explicitly in your data model classes? It would be easier for anyone to answer your question if you post your data model classes code.

Comment: Can you show us `Bestellung.CreateBestellung(...)` ? Your error message indicates that there is no `CreateBestellung` taking the four arguments you try to pass in.

Answer (score 0):

This can only be a wild (but educated) guess. I think the method call should be

```
Bestellung neueBestellung = Bestellung.CreateBestellung(id, anzahl);
```

followed by

```
neueBestellung.kdId = kdId;
neueBestellung.wrId = wrId;
```

Comment: Much appreciated! It gets marked as wrong (no definition for kdId in bestellung) but this doesn't: neueBestellung.Kunde.Id = kdId; Oddly enough, I get a null reference exception now.

Comment: Please, show the method `CreateBestellung` and the class `Bestellung` (by editing your post). As I said, we can only guess now.

Comment: Dear Gert, I found help over the weekend. I will post the result as soon as I receive the file, in case it is helpful to anyone else and also so that you can have a look. Thanks again for your readyness to help!

Comment: neueBestellung.Kunde=kunde; kunde receives its value through a search method that is called earlier and returns a Kunde object - apparently neueBestellung can only work with a complete object, not with just the Id.

Comment: That depends, if you also give it a `KdId` it can handle both. A reference accompanied by a primitive FK value is called _foreign key association_ in Entity Framework. There are many advantages to using these as opposed to _independent associations_ (= reference only, or: `.Kunde` only).

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I'm looking for, I'll be sure to look into it. Thanks for the tip!